# C++ Adding a new class object into a new spot in an array

Tags: c++, arrays, class, visual-c++

i'm new to c++ programming, with previous knowledge about AS3 programming.
My problem is that i cannot figure out how to insert a new object form a class into an array.

Basically what i'm trying to do is:

```
ClassName classArray[];
classArray[n]=new ClassName("Tekst");
```

Here is my code (written using visual studios 2012 C++):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

//a class holding user data
class User
{
public:
    string name;
    User(string nameInn)
    {
        //when the user is created it should get information about its name.
        name=nameInn;
    }
};

//array with all users
User userArr[];
int userArrLength=0; //the length of that array (dont know how to find the length of arays holding classes)

int main()
{
    //the user writes down the name of all users.
    cout << "Write user name. \n Write \"fin\" til finish\n";
    bool hasFinished=false;
    //asks you for a new user until you write fin
    while(hasFinished==false)
    {
        string inn;
        cin >> inn;
        if(inn=="fin") hasFinished=true;
        //here im trying to make a new user inn a new spot in the userArr.
        else userArr[(userArrLength+=1)+1]=new User(inn);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Is my formatting just wrong, if so how do i format it? Or have i misunderstood something essential about classes in C++?

Comment: You're definitely getting errors in this program. Can you list them all down for us?

Comment: I think you must erase java from your head and start with some C++ teaching book. Similar looking things behave quite differently here

Comment: First thing that comes to mind when looking at your first example is: new X() returns a pointer to X so you need an array of pointers to X instead of an array of X.

Comment: @confusopoly maybe they don't need `new` at all?

Comment: @juanchopanza Possibly, but then you get an array of default-constructed objects and calls to the assignment operator of the class for every object you put in the array. And that is something I usually prefer to avoid unless I know that the class implements it properly. Edit: nvm, the class only contains one std::string member so it shouldn't cause any problems.

Comment: @confusopoly not if you use an `std::vector` and just push new elements in.

Comment: @juanchopanza Point taken. I was going by the code in the question here. But std::vector looks like the best solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C++, arrays are of a static size. In addition, new creates a pointer which means you're additionally using the wrong datatype for your array.

The suggested way to go around this would be to use a vector, instead:

```
// At the top
#include <vector>

// Instead of that array
std::vector<User> userVector;

// Inside of the loop
userVector.push_back(User(inn));
```

`std::vector` is essentially a dynamic array.

<del>There is still, however, something to consider: When space is allocated for the vector, all of its members are initialised with the default constructor (ie. the one that can be called without parameters).</del>

<del>If your `User` class has no default constructor If your cl, you will have to insert *pointers* to User (`std::vector<User * > userVector` and `userVector.push_back(new User(inn))`) instead, and manually remove the pointers with `delete` afterwards.</del> (See comment below)

Comment: The last two paragraphs are wrong.  `std::vector` does not require your class to have a default constructor.  Raw memory is allocated, and then objects are constructed in-place, with the copy(or move) constructor. The only time you need a default constructor is if you call the single argument version of `resize`.

Answer (score 2):

[std::vector](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) is a data structure implementing a dynamically sized array that can grow in size as needed. You can use an `std::vector<User>` instead of your own array:

```
#include <vector>

...

  std::vector<User> v;

  // perhaps in a loop
  string inn;
  cin >> inn;
  v.push_back(User(inn));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't change the length of an array once it's been created.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know the size of the array, then you should not be using static arrays. You should be using *dynamic* arrays. Something like this:

```
#include <vector>

std::vector<User> userArr;
```

Here `userArr` will be a vector which has a dynamic size. Then you can change your while loop to do this instead:

```
std::vector<User> arr;

for (std::string in; std::cin >> in && in != "fin";)
{
    arr.push_back( User(in) );
}
```

Comment: std::string in; std::cin >> in && in != "fin";
What does that mean?
Also do you need to use the std:: in those cases?

Comment: @TubeOfJokes All `basic_istream` objects have a boolean operator that when invoked, returns whether the stream has any errors. The `&&` operator tries to convert it to a boolean. That line is basically saying "As long as the user enters in valid input for `in` *and* as long as `in` doesn't equal "fin" after the input, do this...".